# How to convert a pandas series to a numpy array with number of index inside?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series like following:

```
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Now I want to get a numpy array output like:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
```

How can I do it without a for loop?

Comment: `np.repeat(s.index, s)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want an array with N rows (N is the number of elements of the original pd.Series) and 2 columns (a column for the Series index, and a column for the Series values):

```py
array = np.array([series.index, series.values]).T
```

The .T at the end is necessary to have a N,2 instead of a 2,N array.

If you instead want the index followed by the values, do this:

```py
array = np.hstack([series.index, series.values])
```

The NumPy hstack function stacks two arrays (the index and the values) horizontally.